# renewing facebook oauth token BEFORE expiration

Tags: facebook, oauth

Is it possible to renew the long-term oauth token for facebook before it expires, and if so, how is that accomplished? So far it seems facebook will only give back the old token with the same expiration date.
Edit: using server-side authentication, and not finding in the docs specific info on how to request a new short lived token and exchange it for a long-term token using server-side workflow.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is that accomplished?

By getting a new short-lived user access token first, and then sending it to the endpoint for extension.

Comment: Yeah, I read that part of the docs also, but it doesn't seem to work - I do step 1 from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ and always get back the same token. What am I missing?

Comment: It's ok to get the same access token back, did you check if it was renewed ? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I have checked, and the expiration time is the same.

Comment: Server-side auth always gives you a long-lived token already – and that can’t be extended. And it’ll likely give you the same one again, as long as it’s not expired. If you want to get a _new_ long-lived token, then you’ll have to get a new _short-lived_ one through client-side auth first, and then extend that.

Comment: Given all this, we've decided to switch our whole token fetching system to use client-side token fetching which we then exchange server-side for a long term token. This we then reuse for renewing the token, also. Just works out easier.